# Phonegap 2.3.0 and the ForegroundCamera plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins, camera, foreground

I'm using Phonegap 2.3.0 and the new ForegroundCamera plugin from Google Code.. I followed the instructions carefully, and in my Eclipse setup I got the following errors when validating the project:

- Cannot cast from ForegroundCameraLauncher to Plugin
- ctx cannot be resolved or is not a field (x2)
- R cannot be resolved to a variable (x4)
- The method success(PluginResult, String) is undefined for the type
  ForegroundCameraLauncher

Now, I solved the first three of the above errors by updating some deprecated code lines (I hope I got it solved - it doesn't show the errors anymore)..

The first error was corrected by changing Plugin to CordovaPlugin in the line "import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;" in ForegroundCameraLauncher.java.
ctx was replaced with cordova.getActivity() at those two places, where it caused trouble.
This thing with R was fixed by doing some library changes which made it create an R object (sorry, I don't know how to explain this the right way, as I'm not too experienced with Eclipse yet).

With the last one of the four error messages, I tried to make a temporary fix by commenting out those two lines in ForegroundCameraLauncher.java (the lines with "this.success"...). But when taking a picture in my app, it crashes the whole thing upon returning from the camera instance..

Anyone know what's going on? I'd really be happy to get a few pointers here :)

The last error is obviously the one you should be focusing on ;) I just wanted to include some of the error fixing process, if others have experienced the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this commit to see what has changed in Cordova: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/205215d409c4f75e958a9c09c0b4a38bd9a859ac

Replace
`this.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, getRealPathFromURI(uri, this.ctx)), this.callbackId);`
with
`this.callbackContext.success(getRealPathFromURI(uri, cordova));`.

Update the `execute` function as per that commit, and update `takePicture`.

After that I have the ForgroundCamera plugin working with Cordova 2.3. Going to do some more testing and clean up now.

Comment: Nice :) That seems like the solution. Thank you very much. I'll try it out myself, when I've got the time.

Comment: All code errors seem to be gone now, but unfortunately, the plugin crashes my app, even before it shows the camera view..

Answer (score 3):

We have just updated **Foreground Camera Plugin** to work with **Phonegap 2.4.0** and we are working on **Foreground Gallery Plugin** too. Please see http://code.google.com/p/foreground-camera-plugin/ and http://code.google.com/p/foreground-gallery-plugin/, and let us know (post an issue) if you have any problem.

See ya!